# Should a JMS application create a new session for every message that it sends?

Tags: java, jms

Should a JMS application create a new session for every message that it sends or is it preferable to create a session for a long message sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say no in general, though it really depends on the context and on how you logically think of communications in your application.

If message sending is an occasional one-off thing, and subsequent messages are completely unrelated, then yes if you can tolerate the costs.

If you do have a lengthy and logical sequence of interaction, it makes sense to do them within a session as long as you don't mess up your threading.

A session actually provides facilities for a sequence of messages, so by definition it is meant to deal with multiple messages.

Here is what the docs say:

> A session serves several purposes:
>
> ```
> * It is a factory for its message producers and consumers.
>
> * It supplies provider-optimized message factories.
>
> * It supports a single series of transactions that combine work
> ```
>
> spanning its producers and consumers
>   into atomic units.
>
> ```
> * It defines a serial order for the messages it consumes and the
> ```
>
> messages it produces.
>
> ```
> * It retains messages it consumes until they have been acknowledged.
>
> * It serializes execution of message listeners registered with its
> ```
>
> message consumers.

Answer (score 1):

The [class document for Session](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/jms/Session.html) from Sun clearly talks about a single Session object handling messages plural.